# Why system() always return 127 on win7?

Tags: c++, windows-7, cygwin

I'm porting a c++ program from Unix to Win7. The program only does some background computing tasks, it's a command line program. So I use build the program on `cygwin` with `g++` on a 32bit win7 VM.

My target system is a 64bit win7 physical PC. After I copied my program to the target PC, it always fails at a `system()` call. I need to use `system()` to run a `curl` command. This works on my 32bit win7 VM, but always fails on the target 64bit win7 PC.

You may guess if `curl` command has problem. I would say no. Because I can manually run the `curl` command from a cmd window. I also tried to `system("dir")`, it also fails with same error.

On 64bit win7 PC, `system()` always return 127, error is "Permission denied". Does anybody have idea what the problem is.

Comment: Too little information

Comment: could be a -1 as an unsigned value, though thats just a guess. You have to show a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried running your command directly from the console?

Comment: Yes, I can run the command from `cmd` window. `system()` always fails with any command.

Comment: As @user463035818 said, show us a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: You don't need to use `system()` to run `curl` if you use `libcurl` in your project instead. Avoid shelling out to an OS's external command processor when you don't need to.

Comment: I just need to download a file from remote, calling `curl` command is easy. Do you have a simple sample of how to use `libcurl`?

Comment: We really need an [mcve] to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Two points. 1) Use a 64-bit VM to build a program for a 64-bit physical machine. You must have a 32-bit or 64-bit cygwin installed on the physical machine to provide the `cygwin1.dll` with the bitness required by the exe. Use the mingw32 or  mingw64 version of the g++ compiler if you don't want to install cygwin on the physical machine. Use the cygwin `file` command to check the bitness of the exe and to check if it is a cygwin or mingw exe.

2) The windows API provides for a 8-bit return code from a child process to its parent. Using 0 to 127 avoids specifying if the code is signed or unsigned. BTW, there is not `dir.exe`, it is part of command processor, e.g `cmd.exe`.